# Why media Queries Not Working in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have been trying to create a responsive blog on blogger. however I am struck on header part.

Media Queries are Not Working, therefore i am not able to use menu functionality in header.
I have set the menu icon as `display:none` outside media duery and in media query `display:block`

However media query is not able to display menu icon.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<span class="menu-icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></span>
<div class="header section" id="header" name="Header">
<div class="widget Header" data-version="1" id="Header1">
   <div id="header-inner">
      <div class="titlewrapper">
         <h1 class="title">
            learn.dev
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="descriptionwrapper">
         <p class="description"><span>Learning Themes Development</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="widget LinkList" data-version="1" id="LinkList1">
   <h2>Menu</h2>
   <div class="widget-content">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="https://">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://">Disclaimer</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://">Privacy</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-icon {
font-size: 20px;
display: none;
margin-left : 21px;
margin-right : 21px;
cursor : pointer;
)

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your html? Please paste enough code to let others reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added html code

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a minor error in your CSS code.

```
    <style>
    .menu-icon{
        font-size: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-left: 21px;
        margin-right: 21px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }
     @media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
            .menu-icon {
                display: block;
            }

        }
</style>
```